# Chrome Extension Append Input to URL.

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently creating a Chrome Extension that has a popup.html and in that pop up is 2 things. An input field and Submit button.

The Input field takes a EXTN number from a user and when submitted is pressed I need to then navigate the user to a new tab appending the Input from the user to the end.

Input = 9999 when submit is pressed user is taken to: Submit = http://name.com/9999

I have this working with when just use the HTML file but it doesn't seem to do anything when loaded into Chrome as an Extension.

Here is my code for the input and onClick:

Popup.HTML

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="page" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
```

popup.js

```
function goToPage() {
var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
window.location = "http://name.com/" + page; }
```

I understand that you can't run in line JS so I've called it out from the popup.js file but its still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't use inline JS in Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) (the `onclick="goToPage();"` in the input element is considered inline Javascript) . You have to put **all** your Javascript code in a separate file.

You will need to use [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API to open a new tab. For example:

**popup.html**

```
<input type="text" id="page" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){
    var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
    chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://name.com/' + page});
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize the onClick is considered inline JavaScript. This works exactly how i expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

5 years late to the party here, but thinking about using this as a method to quick make a search query for shipments, if possible.

I already have an unrelated JS bookmark, it looks like this:
`javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`
and wonder if this url method of js input can be used to append the user input to the url, the same way the popup.html and .js does. So I click the bookmark and I get a popup box I have to enter the number in and press enter. I can host my own popup.js file if needed and the chrome.tabs.create url goes to the search url.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35402709)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).