# Chrome Extension- Take input from user and append to websites to open them in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi i am creating a google chrome extension which will take input from the user and append that input to some particular urls i have in my javascript file and then open those websites in new tab. But its not working. i am pasting my extension popup.html and popup.js files here.
What am i doing wrong here?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('Submit_btn').addEventListener('click', main);

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var text = x.elements[0].value;
    if (text.localeCompare("One") == 0) {
      var t = x.elements[1].value;
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + t);
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + t);
      window.open("http://www.example.com/" + t);
    } else if (text.localeCompare("Two") == 0) {
      var t = x.elements[1].value;
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + t);
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + t);
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + t);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="frm1">
    <select name="List">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <br><br> Query: <input type="text" name="fname" id="frm2"><br>
  </form>

  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="Submit_btn">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982518/3930351) for a similar question.

Comment: Use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) instead of `window.open`.

Comment: There is no function called `main`. Besides, you can't use inline Javascript in a chrome extension. Check for errors in the popup by right-clicking on the extension's icon and select 'Inspect pop-up'.

Comment: I tried debugging it but i am not able to do so. Can you please write a sample code for my clarification. I am new to chrome extension development